# How to stop the execution of my java program after i invoke r.exec to start a cmd prompt

Tags: java, batch-file, command, prompt, runtime.exec

in my program i am using 
**r.exec();** to start the command prompt and execute a bat file in it.

But what happens is, as soon as the above statement is executed cmd prompt starts and executes the bat file in it.However, the java program execution will not wait until the bat file is executed in the prompt ie.
It starts the cmd prompt & starts executing the bat file in it and continues with the execution of next statements after **r.exec();**.(Meanwhile my bat file is still being executed in the prompt)

My requirement is that, java program must wait until the bat file in command prompt is executed rather than continuing with the execution of next statements.

Comment: Do you mean `Runtime.exec()`? If so, that returns a `Process`, and you can just wait for that to finish. If not, please clarify what `r` is.

Comment: Yes its Runtime.exec().
But how can i wait until that is done executing?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec` returns a `Process` instance. On that instance you can call `waitFor()` to wait for the Process to complete.

In addition you need to handle `Process.getErrorStream()` and `Process.getOutputStream()` (usually in a separate Thread) so the Process will not block when these Buffers fill up. `ProcessBuilder` with `redirectErrorStream(true)` has a handy method that removes the need to handle two streams at once and therfor the additional thread.

Answer (score 0):

`r.exec("command")` returns `Process`. From here you can simply put the following:

```
Process process = r.exec("command here");
process.waitFor(); //Waits until process closes
```

The `waitFor()` method will pause this current thread until the process has closed.

> [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) `waitFor()`: Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated

Further more, if you want to capture input or send commands to the console, you could use `process.getInputStream()` and `process.getOutputStream()` in separate threads. This would let you monitor the batch file as it runs, so you could cancel terminate process if it breaks down for some reason.